# Suma de Valores con Llave Primaria Repetida en un DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, group-by

Quisiera saber la forma de realizar la suma de los valores en la columna Transacciones de cada valor que se repite en la columna Cliente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se tienen 3 clientes diferentes (30,40 & 50) quisiera colocar la suma de sus transacciones en una columna al final correspondiendo cada cliente; ej, Cliente 30, Suma de Transacciones 16+2 = 18
Lo realice con la sig. línea de suma acumulada, sin obtener resultados exitosos.

```
df['CumSum'] = df.groupby(['Cliente','Piezas']).cumsum()[['Transacciones']]
```

Answer (score 3):

Si quieres hacer la suma de `Transacciones`. Puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'cliente':[30,30,40,40,40,50,50,50,50],
                   'piezas':[1,2,1,2,3,2,4,5,6],
                   'transacciones':[16,2,10,2,24,2,2,3,1],
                   'cumSum':[18,18,36,36,36,8,8,8,8]})


df.groupby('cliente')['transacciones'].sum()
```

La salida será asi :

```
cliente
30    18
40    36
50     8
Name: transacciones, dtype: int64
```

Eso que te esta mostrando es una `serie`. Si quieres verlo como un `DataFrame` , basta con aplanar los indices, con `reset_index()`

```
df.groupby('cliente')['transacciones'].sum().reset_index()
```

y la salida sera asi:

```
cliente transacciones
  30        18
  40        36
  50        8
```

En tu publicación hiciste el groupby con `clientes` y `piezas`. Si lo quieres hacer con esos dos campos, solo tienes que enviarlos como una lista, tal cual lo realizaste en tu ejemplo. :

```
df.groupby(['cliente'.'piezas'])['transacciones'].sum()
```